# How to get data for fs.createReadStream

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I am trying to get data from a csv file but I am getting the fs.readStream object instead

```
const fs = require("fs");
const csv = require("csv-parser");
const path = require("path");

const file = path.resolve(__dirname, "./file");

export const parseCsv = async () => {
  const result = [];

  return await fs
    .createReadStream(file)
    .pipe(csv())
    .on("data", (data) => {
      result.push(data);
    })
    .on("end", () => {
      const obj = {};
      result.forEach((service) => {
        if (!obj[service.code]) {
          obj[service.code] = service.rate;
        }
      });
      console.log(obj);
      return obj; // looking to get this
    });
};
```

I'm am creating an object map of the csv file and looking to get that data but I keep getting this instead.

```
CsvParser {
  _readableState: ReadableState {
    objectMode: true,
    highWaterMark: 16,
    buffer: BufferList { head: null, tail: null, length: 0 },
    length: 0,
    pipes: [],
    flowing: true,
    ended: false,
    endEmitted: false,
    reading: false,
    constructed: true,
    sync: false,
    needReadable: false,
    emittedReadable: false,
    readableListening: false,
    resumeScheduled: true,
    etc...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`await` only does something useful when you `await` a promise and `fs.createReadStream().pipe().on()` returns a stream, not a promise.  I would suggest you wrap this stream code in a promise where you can then `resolve()` and `reject()` the promise appropriately.

Then, the caller will use `await` or `.then()` on the returned promise to get access to the final result.

```
const fs = require("fs");
const csv = require("csv-parser");
const path = require("path");

const file = path.resolve(__dirname, "./file");

export const parseCsv = () => {
    const result = [];
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        fs.createReadStream(file)
            .pipe(csv())
            .on("data", (data) => {
                result.push(data);
            }).on("end", () => {
                const obj = {};
                result.forEach((service) => {
                    if (!obj[service.code]) {
                        obj[service.code] = service.rate;
                    }
                });
                console.log(obj);
                resolve(obj);
            }).on(error, reject);
    });
}
```

Comment: This worked perfectly thank you. I'm still not sure why wrapping it in a promise changed the behavior like that. What I mean is if fs.createReadStream isn't returning a promise then I should just be able to return the value right?

Comment: @MichaelSanford - No, streams are asynchronous.  Your function returns immediately and then the stream runs its events later, long after your function has returned.  You cannot directly return the final value.   Your `return obj` statement is the return from an event handler callback, NOT a return from your function.  Your function had long since returned before that ever occurred.